# How can I make the edge of a carving line have the solid color after I draw it

Tags: ios, core-graphics

As we all know, after we draw a carving line, there are some pixels with half-transparent colors, like the following.

[image]

I don't know how to call the phenomenon, maybe cause by the "Blend mode" or "premultiply alpha", I want to know how can I ignore these none-solid pixels, thanks.
My draw code:

```
guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
ctx.addPath(path)
ctx.setLineCap(.round)
ctx.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
ctx.setStrokeColor(lineColor.cgColor)
ctx.setBlendMode(.normal)
ctx.setAlpha(lineAlpha)
ctx.strokePath()
```

I have a solution which is generating image from the ctx, then changing the half-transparent pixels to solid ones, then drawing the image back to the ctx. It makes sense, but it has a performance issue, so do we have a way to fix it when drawing the line? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called "anti-aliasing". Turn it off using [`CGContext.setShouldAntialias(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext/1455178-setshouldantialias) before you do your drawing, like so:

```swift
guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
ctx.addPath(path)
ctx.setLineCap(.round)
ctx.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
ctx.setStrokeColor(lineColor.cgColor)
ctx.setBlendMode(.normal)
ctx.setAlpha(lineAlpha)
ctx.setShouldAntialias(false) // <------
ctx.strokePath()
```